# Using Bootstrap in React to display a responsive gallery

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

I want to display a responsive image gallery using `React` and `Bootstrap`.
I want to have 2 `columns` per `row` in on small devices and 3 columns per row on medium and larger devices.
At the moment my items wrap onto to next row too soon, leaving the last column empty. Any ideas what is wrong with my Bootstrap?

Here is my code:

```
        return(
        <div className='App'>
          <h2> View Images </h2>
          <div className='container-fluid' >
            <div className='row'>
              {
                rounds.map((item,index)=>{
                  return(
                    <div key={index} className='col-sm-6 col-md-4'>
              
                    <img src={item.url} 
                          alt={`image_${item.url}`}
                          height="200" 
                      />
                    <br />ID:  {item.id}
                    </div>
                  )
                })
              }
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
```

here is my screen [Bootstrap rows and columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXgNK.png)

I can see that my row is split into 2 columns however the second column is not populated with the image as expected, instead the image wraps onto the next row

Comment: Does it show the images in 2 columns on larger screen widths?

Comment: @Zim. Yes, Each row shows 2 images on larger screens (instead of 3), and If I add another responsive breakpoint such as col-lg-3, each row will show 3 images (instead of 4)

Comment: So at what screen width is it showing them in a single column?

Comment: At the moment, they are being displayed in a single column on small devices (mobile) but as per my "className" properties I want 2 image columns on Small devices. I do not ever want a single column.

Answer (score 0):

Use `col-6` instead of `col-sm-6`...

```
   return(
        <div className='App'>
          <h2> View Images </h2>
          <div className='container-fluid' >
            <div className='row'>
              {
                rounds.map((item,index)=>{
                  return(
                    <div key={index} className='col-6 col-md-4'>
              
                    <img src={item.url} 
                          alt={`image_${item.url}`}
                          height="200" 
                      />
                    <br />ID:  {item.id}
                    </div>
                  )
                })
              }
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: Unfortunateley this doesn't solve the problem. I can see still 2 columns when I hover over the div element with ClassName = "row"  but only the first column is populated with an image.